# Cannot ping EC2 instance from AWS CloudShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ping

- I cannot ping the private IP either from the AWS CloudShell or another EC2 instance:

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-0-161-171 ~]$ ping 10.1.0.10
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

- Ping is enabled on the instance:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
0
```

- The Image is: **amzn2-ami-kernel-5.10-hvm-2.0.20220606.1-x86_64-gp2**
- The ping arrives in that subnet (i can see that with tcpdump)
- The SG Rule is as follows (I replaced personal data with "..."):
  [ICMP Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZy0p.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately not allowed in CloudShell

> Cause: The ping utility uses Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP)
> to send echo requests packets to a target host. It then waits for an
> echo reply from the target. Because the ICMP protocol isn't enabled in
> AWS CloudShell, the ping utility doesn't operate in the shell's
> compute environment.
> `

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Ok thanks, but I thought this was only meant for *external* IP addresses. But I tried to ping an internal (private) IP address ...

Comment: That link says "Because the ICMP protocol isn't enabled in AWS CloudShell" which means you can't ping at all. A workaround is to install Nginx or Apache and use curl, which isn't a great workaround really.